# python write to SQL file

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

Hello i am using python 3.4

I am trying to read a SQL-file (`test2.sql`)
and write each line to another file (`test1.sql`), replacing all occurrences of a string.

The code i have below works fine when writing to `.txt`-files, but when trying to write to `.sql`-files strange Chinese characters trail each line

```
import fileinput
import sys

g = open('test1.sql', mode='w')
with fileinput.input(files=("test2.sql")) as f:
    for line in f:
        g.write(line.replace("database1","database2"))
```

Comment: Where do you see these strange characters? Are you opening the same file and just writing to a different file?

Comment: on the new file (test.1) where i expect a new line to be i get characters ਍ഀ 
*apolgies confused read and write file

Answer (score 1):

You cannot meaningfully manipulate strings in a database as if it were a plain-text file.

You need to use the database native access method to ensure that the meta-data in the database is consistent. If you do otherwise, you are nearly guaranteed to corrupt database structures.

I'm a bit surprised this worked at all. It is likely that the next database modification (create, remove, update, delete) would hopelessly corrupt the database.

Comment: i am not writing to a database, all i want to do is replace strings in a sql file without having strange characters for line endings when am viewing it using notepad

Comment: If by "sql file" you mean "SQL commands in a plain text file" then the strange characters are likely encoding problems. See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html for annoyingly complex details. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html would also help. I don't know if Notepad.exe allows you to chose an encoding, but (free) [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) does.